# Change Putty Home drive

Tags: putty

I login  to SCO Unix server using Putty 0.60 working on puppy linux. What i need to do is set the Home directory for the user. I mean, I want the users to be able to save their data on the local machine which has hdb1 or in a usb drive sdb1. Can you pl help me how to do it from a local machine (Thin client).
Thanks in advance
crsrds

Comment: Please *don't* use signatures or taglines in your posts. http://superuser.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

Edit the /etc/passwd file

find the entry for the user in question, it will look something like -

```
dave:x:1000:1000:Dave,,,:/home/dave:/bin/bash
```

Change `/home/dave` to whatever you want.